# Get URL from onclick attribute of a tag python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to access a URL which is present in onclick attribute of a tag using selenium  python. It is present in the javascript function. I have tried various techniques to do so but I haven't found the solution yet.
I have tried executing the on click function using execute_script method. I have also tried get_attribute to get the onclick function but it returns none. 
I want to access the url present in openPopUpFullScreen function

Here's the html:

```
<td class="tdAction">
<div class="formResponseBtn icon-only">
<a href="#fh" onclick="javascript: openPopUpFullScreen('/esop/toolkit/negotiation/rfq/publicRfqSummaryReport.do?rfqId=rfq_229969', '');" class="openNewPage" title="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions">
<img src="/esop_custom/images/buttons/print_button.png" title="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions" alt="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions"><img src="/esop_custom/images/buttons/openNewWindow_button.png" title="(Opens in new window)" alt="(Opens in new window)">
</a>
</div>
</td>
```

Here's the python code:

```
url=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions']").click()
print(browser.current_url)
#it returns the previous page I am at.
```

Here's another one:

```
id=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".openNewPage").get_attribute("onclick")
print(id)
#it returns none
```

I need the URL present in openPopUpFullScreen function but I am not able to figure out what would be the right solution to get this done.

Update: I have also tried using beautifulsoup for extraction of the onclick function but it doesn't seem to appear:

Here's my code:

```
content = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
res = soup.find("a",{"class":"openNewPage"})
print(res)
#it returns the complete tag but it does not contain onclick attribute
#i tried using this
res = soup.find("a",{"class":"openNewPage"})[onclick]
#it returns an error NameError: name 'onclick' is not defined
```

Comment: Try ***['onclick']*** instead of ***[onclick]***

Comment: it returns __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'onclick'

Comment: It seems you are already using a browser simulator. Use some delay in order for the page to be loaded completely.

Comment: Yes I am using selenium but as I mentioned above when I use the get_attirbute function with selenium it returns none. Before executing this colde I already have time.sleep(10) in place.

Comment: use presence_of_element_located: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: You are printing browser.current_url instead of url.

Comment: Maybe it's exist multiple elements with class="openNewPage"?

Comment: @NielsDrost actually the function present in the page opens a new window, I need the url of the new window hence I used current_url but it returns the url of the page from where I opened the new window.

Comment: @Yun yes there might me be multiple entries because I am iterating through a lot of pages and on some pages .openNewPage might be more than one. I was using find_elements_by_css_selector first but I switched to find_element_by_css_selector so that if I could get one right then I could easily place a for loop for multiple elements.

Comment: At his point it is hard to provide you with any working solution unless you share the site link @Prakhar Sood. Thanks.

Comment: https://e-sourcingni.bravosolution.co.uk/esop/toolkit/opportunity/opportunityDetail.do?opportunityId=45520&oppList=CURRENT
here's the url need to scrape the url in published lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<td class="tdAction">
<div class="formResponseBtn icon-only">
<a href="#fh" onclick="javascript: openPopUpFullScreen('/esop/toolkit/negotiation/rfq/publicRfqSummaryReport.do?rfqId=rfq_229969', '');" class="openNewPage" title="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions">
<img src="/esop_custom/images/buttons/print_button.png" title="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions" alt="Open a new window to view > View or download a Summary of this PQQ/ITT which includes details of the PQQ/ITT settings, format and questions"><img src="/esop_custom/images/buttons/openNewWindow_button.png" title="(Opens in new window)" alt="(Opens in new window)">
</a>
</div>
</td>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
a = soup.find('a')
onclick = a.attrs['onclick']
left = onclick.find("'")
right = onclick.find("'",left+1)
print('URL is: {}'.format(onclick[left+1:right]))
```

output

```
URL is: /esop/toolkit/negotiation/rfq/publicRfqSummaryReport.do?rfqId=rfq_229969
```

Comment: onclick = a.attrs['onclick']
KeyError: 'onclick' I am getting this

Comment: @PrakharSood did you copy/paste my code and got the key error?

Comment: No I applied it in my code where the variable html contains the url of the page.

Comment: @PrakharSood So start by checking my code. My code is based on the HTML you have posted and it works. Once you understand the code works  - check what is wrong with the way you use it in your code.

Comment: Cheers mate! I reviewed my code and found the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For get_attribute:

I think you get the wrong element without 'onclick' attribute.

You should extend css selector and confirm that it will find only one element.

---

For current_url:

You should switch to new window first.
Try to use below code:

```
# window_handles[-1] refer to last window created.
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
print(browser.current_url)
```